# Why the compiler gives an error when I'm right-clicking NOT on the UI element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My compiler gives an error ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the file List.cs when I click on the empty space but if I click on the UI elements it's doesn't gives an error. But how it gives an error if I have a check

```
if (results != null)
```

There is my code :

```
public void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        eventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
        eventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        _raycaster.Raycast(eventData, results);

        if (results != null)
        {
            if (results[0].gameObject.tag == "ItemIcon")
            {
                if(currentMenu != null)
                {
                    Destroy(currentMenu);
                }
                currentMenu = Instantiate(SplitMenu, transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please try `results.Count != 0` instead of `null`

Comment: Actually, consider `if (results != null && results.Any()) { ...`.  The exception is very likely the result of you looking for the first element in an empty collection. By the way, that's an exception thrown by your code, it's not emitted by the compiler.

Comment: Ali Kanat, it helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

     _raycaster.Raycast(eventData, results);

2.    if (results != null)
    {
3.        if (results[0].gameObject.tag == "ItemIcon")
```

Line 1 initialises `results`, so that check on line 3 will never be false.  Just because results is initialised, doesn't mean it has any entries in it, so line 3 will give an error if there are no results.

As others have pointed out, line 2 should be:

```
if(results.Any())
```

`.Any()` is better that `.Count > 0` because it implies the intent that 'something is in the list', rather than 'the count is greater than 0'.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are checking that results != null, but you are not checking if results actually has any elements in it.  So using results[0] on an empty array results in the ArgumentOutOfRangeException you are seeing.

Adding `&& results.Any()` to the if check should resolve it.

Comment: Or just `&& result[0] != null` since anyway only `results[0]` is used later. Prevents unnecessary gc activity caused by using LinQ

Comment: @derHugo: No, `&& result[0] != null` would throw the same exception. `results.Count != 0` is more efficient than using `Any` though, assuming this is a `List<T>`.

Comment: If you want to avoid Linq, you could do ```results.Length > 0``` as well (or is it .Count?  It's been a while since I've worked with C# and I can't remember if Count was another LInq extension or not).

Comment: @CodeMonkey: `Count()` is an extension method, `Count` is a property in `IList<T>`/`IReadOnlyList<T>` etc. `Length` is the property on arrays... yay for consistency ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best option : we need to use `results.Count != 0` instead of `null`.